# sqlite3_step return code 21 during loadView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Experimenting with sqlite, I want to init a list view with data from the DB. My source looks like this:

```
-(void) initTheList {
sqlite3 *db;
int rows = 0;

const char* dbFilePathUTF8 = [searchTermDBLocation UTF8String];
int dbrc = sqlite3_open( dbFilePathUTF8, &db );

// count
if (dbrc) {
    NSLog( @"Could not open the DB" );
} else {
    NSString *queryStatementNS = @"select count(*) from article";
    const char* queryStatement = [queryStatementNS UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt *dbps;
    dbrc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStatement, -1, &dbps, NULL);

    if (sqlite3_step(dbps) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        rows = sqlite3_column_int(dbps, 0);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"SQL step failed code: %d", sqlite3_step(dbps));
        NSLog(@"Attempted Query: %@", queryStatementNS);
    }

    [queryStatementNS release];
}

if (rows > 1000) { ... } else { ... };
...
```

Actually I thought it would be good to envoke the code only one time once the view is loaded. So I added the initialization of the array and the method call to:

```
- (void)loadView {
   [super loadView];
   tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
   [self initTheList];
}
```

However, doing so, sqlite3_step returns x15 (SQLITE_MISUSE 21 /* Library used incorrectly */). If I place the code to invoke the method in the numberOfRowsInSection method, the call works fine.

Can somebody please give me a hint where I can learn more about the lifecycles and the relation to the sqlite database? It surprises me that I can open the DB but reading fails, while the same code placed in a method that is obviously called at a later point in time works fine.

Comment: Since you are experimenting with SQLite, that implies you are new to it.  Unless you have a very explicit need for SQLite, go explore Core Data instead.  Writing raw SQL is generally a waste of time.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will investigate on Core Data. However, I would be still interested why selecting data from the sqlite DB works in the one case but doesn't in the other one.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the error code 21 problem myself ("Library used incorrectly.") I couldn't find any helpful answers on the Web, and I was just about ready to conclude that there was some bug in the SQLite3 library in XCode. And then, at long last, I found my problem: a subtle typo in my SQL.

The error was happening during an INSERT OR REPLACE statement. But that particular statement itself had no typo, so I didn't find where I went wrong for the longest time. The database file was being created, so I ran a (Unix) strings command on it, and discovered that I had created a typo in one of the field names during the table's creation. The table created fine, but with *the wrong field name.* When I was doing the INSERT OR REPLACE, I was using the *correct* field name. Ah! The mismatch caused the error.

I don't know if this is your problem; but it is very easy to make a typo when creating SQL statements, and they aren't always easy to track down (as I just demonstrated to myself this afternoon). If I were you, I would double check every statement you have.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Today I discovered that error 21 is returned by sqlite3_step() if the prepared statement pointer happens to be NULL (zero).